# Mysql - Retornar ultimas datas

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Estou montando um query que precisa retornar as ultimas (mais recentes) datas em uma tabela MySql. O campo dessa coluna é `timestamp()` no seguinte formato: mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss (ex. 2023-01-11 12:07:18)

Cheguei a montar essa query, mas ela retorna somente a ultima linha da tabela, e eu necessito de todas a linhas que possuem essa data.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(dataHoraCotacao, "%m-%d-%Y") as dataHoraCotacao, tipoBoletim 
  from homologdolarhistorico 
     where dataHoraCotacao = (select max(dataHoraCotacao) from homologdolarhistorico);
```

Comment: *"eu necessito de todas a linhas que possuem essa data"* e todas tem a mesma data, hora, min, seg, etc? pq no `where dataHoraCotacao =` diz que precisa ser exatamente a mesma data, por causa do `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você faz:

```
select max(dataHoraCotacao) from homologdolarhistorico
```

Ele vai te retornar a última data/hora desta tabela. Se você quer apenas a data, deve usar a função date. A consulta acima ficaria desta forma

```
select date(max(dataHoraCotacao)) from homologdolarhistorico
```

Você precisaria ajustar a sua consulta para retornar o que for igual ou maior que esta data. Sua consulta atualizada ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(dataHoraCotacao, "%m-%d-%Y") as dataHoraCotacao, tipoBoletim 
  from homologdolarhistorico 
     where dataHoraCotacao >= (select date(max(dataHoraCotacao)) from homologdolarhistorico);
```

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado!!